# getopt - push default value if the argument is not provided

Tags: shell, getopts

Im following this guide to using [getopt](https://www.shellscript.sh/tips/getopt/).

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
ALPHA=test
BETA=test
CHARLIE=test
DELTA=test

usage()
{
  echo "Usage: alphabet [ -a | --alpha ] [ -b | --beta ]
                        [ -c | --charlie CHARLIE ] 
                        [ -d | --delta   DELTA   ] filename(s)"
  exit 2
}

PARSED_ARGUMENTS=$(getopt -a -n alphabet -o a:b:c:d: --long alpha:,bravo:,charlie:,delta: -- "$@")
VALID_ARGUMENTS=$?
if [ "$VALID_ARGUMENTS" != "0" ]; then
  usage
fi

 eval set -- "$PARSED_ARGUMENTS"
while :
do
  case "$1" in
    -a | --alpha)   ALPHA="$2"      ; shift 2   ;;
    -b | --beta)    BETA="$2"    ; shift  2 ;;
    -c | --charlie) CHARLIE="$2" ; shift 2 ;;
    -d | --delta)   DELTA="$2"   ; shift 2 ;;
     --) shift; break ;;
     *) echo "Unexpected option: $1 - this should not happen."
       usage ;;
  esac
done

echo "ALPHA   : $ALPHA"
echo "BETA    : $BETA "
echo "CHARLIE : $CHARLIE"
echo "DELTA   : $DELTA"
echo "Parameters remaining are: $@"
```

So all of the arguments are mandatory, if we didn't give the argument then it'll return the default value (where I have assigned from the beginning)

### EX:

```bsh
./script
PARSED_ARGUMENTS is  --
ALPHA   : unset
BETA    : unset
CHARLIE : unset
DELTA   : unset
```

### Ex2

```bsh
./script -a aaa
PARSED_ARGUMENTS is  -a 'aaa' --
ALPHA   : aaa
BETA    : unset
CHARLIE : unset
DELTA   : unset
Parameters remaining are:
```

Till here it is perfect.

### Issue:

Now, if Im calling the argument but not giving any values while triggering the script, then its throwing error.

```bsh
./script -a
alphabet: option requires an argument -- 'a'
Usage: alphabet [ -a | --alpha ] [ -b | --beta ]
                        [ -c | --charlie CHARLIE ]
                        [ -d | --delta   DELTA   ] filename(s)
```

In this case, if I didn't give the values for `-a` then it should take the value from the default.(from the beginning)

Comment: It's _very rare_ that a utility behaves the way that you describe. If the user is giving the `-a` option, they do so to _change its default value_. Not giving an argument to `-a` should therefore be an error. Also your use of `unset` is a bit confusing. It should really say `default`. A variable with the value `unset` is clearly _set_ to that value.

Comment: Oh its just copied from the site I referred, Its a default value, like `'test'`, I have updated the question

Comment: Yes, but the code at the end of the link does not have option-arguments to some of its options. (you have `a:b:c:d:`, they have another string).

Comment: If i remove the `:` then `./script  -a aaa` this is not working.

Comment: Well, you have to make up your mind. Should `-a` take an argument or not? Because you can't do both.

Comment: Your example runs don't match your code. Everywhere you show `unset` it should show `test`

Comment: Yeah correct, :)  getopts have an option for this , but there the long options are not supported. But its ok. I have to give the value or I'll ignore the argument so it'll take the default one.

Comment: `getopt` has been declared outdated 35 years ago, why do you use it? Better use `getopts`.

Comment: Oh is it? But I guess getopts doesn't support long arguments

Comment: `getopt` is non-standard and not granted to exist. In contrary to `getopt` that does not support long options, important `getopts` implementations  include portable support for long options and support for `+option` that may even soon become part of POSIX. See the current Bourne Shell man page at: http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man1/bosh.1.html - currently at page 47  `ksh93` has a compatible implementation.

Comment: @schily there are two `getopt` implementations (at least). There's the ancient obsolete one that was replaced with the built-in `getopts`. Now there's a newer `getopt` that supports short and long arguments. Probably not available yet on all platforms but definitely alive and kicking. On the contrary I've not yet seen a `getopts` that supports long arguments.

Comment: @roaima `getopt` has been given up in the mid 1980s since it cannot support arguments with spaces inside. `getopts` is a shell builtin and is based on the `getopt()` function in libc that suports long options since more than 20 years. Given that this is using a portable concept that works 100% compatible in `ksh93`, I strongly discourage people from using the Linux-only `getopt` implementation, since the rest of the world agrees in `getopt` being outdated. Scripts that depend on that `getopt` will not work at all if outside Linux.

Comment: Like I say, there are _two versions_ of `getopt`. The obsolete one, which you keep harping on about, and a more recent one that is immune to the issues you've raised. This (in)compatibility issue is even described in the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt) for the more modern version.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just give "-a" and leave it without argument rather you just don't mention "-a" at all and inside the script if -a option is not given , you can assign a default value like below:

```
if [[ -z $ALPHA ]]
then
ALPHA="defaultvalue"
fi
```